# Oracle 11g SQL Disable foreign key constraints and drop table

Tags: sql, oracle

When I have issued a 
ALTER TABLE table DISABLE CONSTRAINT fk1

and when I then try to drop the table

DROP TABLE table

That the constraint is still checked even though it is disabled.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Try this
`DROP TABLE table CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DISABLE CONSTRAINT works for update/insert statements.

See oracle help.

[Disabling Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general005.htm#ADMIN11538)

> To enforce the rules defined by integrity constraints, the constraints
>   should always be enabled. However, consider temporarily disabling the
>   integrity constraints of a table for the following performance
>   reasons:
>
> When loading large amounts of data into a table
>
> When performing batch operations that make massive changes to a table
>   (for example, changing every employee's number by adding 1000 to the
>   existing number)
>
> When importing or exporting one table at a time

You are trying to drop your table. It is not designed to for this. You need to DROP CONSTRAINTs.

Answer (score 8):

You have to drop the constraints as well in order drop a table. Try the following:

```
DROP TABLE someTable CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
```